# Return NSIndexPath from custom cell ? (UITableView)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsindexpath

I need to get the `NSIndexPath` for a custom cell in a `UITableView`. Here's the problem: I send a `NSNotification` from my custom cell to my `UITableViewController` when `editingDidBegin` gets called from a `UITextField` in my custom cell. In my `UITableViewController`, I resize the `UITableView` when the `UITextField` began editing, and then want the table view to scroll to the Cell in which the `UITextField` is first responder. But I can't figure out how to return the `indexPath` of the cell where the `UITextField` is being edited. I have tried so many ways, but its still not working. One way is this: in my cstomCell class i select the row using `[self setSelected:YES]` and in my TV controller then if I `NSLog` the row of `[self.tableV indexPathForSelectedRow]` it always returns 0 even though its always not 0.

Comment: wouldn't you rather just get his `frame`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just give the cell a value for its `tag` property.  Then you can get that cell by calling this

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.tableView viewWithTag:tagValue];
```

then once you have the cell you can get the NSIndexPath like this

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:nextResponderCell];
```

Since you have a UITextField in your custom cell you can place `cell.textField.delegate = self;` in the

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

data source method.  That way you will not have to setup a NSNotification in the Custom Cell.  Also in this same method you can tag both your cells text field like this `cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row;` and the cell like this `cell.tag = indexPath.row;`

Now that you have set the UITextField delegate, you can now place this method in your UITableViewController class

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[self.tableView viewWithTag:textField.tag];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];        

}
```

The above UITextField delegate method should get you the indexPath for the cell you have currently selected.

Comment: I don't get it, please provide some more code. There is no relation between the two lines of code, please tell me where to put which line of code.

Comment: @Maxner I have edited my answer.  Hope that clears up any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

try this code..

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UITableView *tableView;
    UITableViewCell* superViewCell = [self returnSuperCellViewOfTextField:textField];
    if(superViewCell)[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForCell:superViewCell] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
}

-(id)returnSuperCellViewOfTextField:(id)viewToCheck
{
    id superView = [viewToCheck superview];
    if([viewToCheck isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]] && superView)return superView;
    else if(([viewToCheck respondsToSelector:@selector(superview)] && superView)) return [self returnSuperCellViewOfTextField:superView];
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this (your answer that you gave before below)still works if you have multiple texfields in each cell?:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.tableView viewWithTag:tagValue];
then once you have the cell you can get the NSIndexPath like this

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:nextResponderCell];
```

Since you have a `UITextField` in your custom cell you can place `cell.textField.delegate = self;` in the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

data source method. Also in this same method you can tag both your cells text field like this cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row; and the cell like this cell.tag = indexPath.row;

Now that you have set the UITextField delegate, you can now place this method in your UITableViewController class

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[self.tableView viewWithTag:textField.tag];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

I have a tableview with 8 cells, and in each cell i have 6 texfields, and also the tableview is dynamic, so the user can insert more cells...but i´m having trouble in how to save the text the user enters in each texfield. Is it possible that with "cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row", the controller identify´s the texfield i´m in?

Answer (score -1):

I like to tag my cells like so:

```
/* Create a tag based on the section and row of a cell(used to retrive the cell for the beginEditingNextCell method. */
-(NSInteger)tagForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)path {
    return path.section * 1000 + path.row + 1;
}
```

The other way is to pass the beginEditing data using a custom delegate, and include a cell model, which you can then use to figure out your path depending on how you are storing data.

Check out my github project, it has the code to handle this case, as well as resizing for the keyboard and tabbing to the next editable cell: https://github.com/andrewzimmer906/XCell

Comment: Your github project is a complete mess, at least 20 errors and warnings on build. Could you please provide me some more code, just related to my question? I have an open bounty of 50.